# JavaScript inherit object values

Tags: javascript

[image]

[image]

in `extend()` function, the output of the source is

`{ add: [Function: add], show: [Function: show] }` see line 14

but in for-loop there are another new property called extend?? why

Comment: Please add your code in a code block directly in your question instead of posting screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop will look into the prototype chain of an object. Here is a good [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) on it.

To avoid this, inside the loop you can make an if statement that checks if the property is part of the object.

```
for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    console.log('this is fog (' + name + ') for sure. Value: ' + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

See more details about [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: But why there will increase a new property, because I output the results, the results are different from final result. where this new property comes from?

Comment: This is how javascript prototype inheritance works, it's a great part of the language. To explain it fully goes beyond the scope of what stackoverflow is for, have a read of the articles I linked to. If you make a class and a subclass the subclass inherits all the methods of the class via the prototype chain. When you call a method on an instance of the subclass that can't be found it will move up the prototype chain one level at a time until it finds the method. This is how all the classes you make have the basic methods all objects share.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my view about inheritance, I think it just a pointer to refer to superType prototype, so when I use for-loop, it will traversal  until object prototype? is it right?

Comment: That's exactly it.